# Bind <select> with multi options in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have a form where the user can add some sort of categories and add some options to those categories.
When the user enter the data for the category and its items, I dynamically add them in a `<select>`, where the category is the `<optgroup>`, so I can bind it to some ViewModel property, it looks like this after the user entered the data:

```
<select asp-for="Items">
   <optgroup label="Brands">
       <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
       <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
       <option value="Brand3">Brand3</option>
       <option value="Brand4">Brand4</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Something">
       <option value="Something1" selected>Something1</option>
       <option value="Something2" selected>Something2</option>
       <option value="Something3" selected>Something3</option>
       <option value="Something4" selected>Something4</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Then I try to bind this to the `Items` property in the ViewModel, but the only way I can bind this, is with the `Items` of the type `List<string>`.
This way I lost the Group each option belongs to.
How could I bind it for something like a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where I can keep the grouping that I did on the html?

PS.: The select will be invisible, its only a way for me to get the data in some structure that I can submit in a form. The presentation will be done in some sort of tags. 
Like:

[image]

Comment: You cannot. A `<select>` only posts back the values of its selected options (and binds to `IEnumerable<string>`). Nothing related to its `<optgroup>` are sent in the request.

Comment: Isn't there any way other than making the `value="brand__brandname"` of each option and dealing it on the controller ?

Comment: Short answer - No.

Answer (score 1):

I admit, I'm not sure if this answer is quite what you are asking, since I rarely use ViewModels in my app. I'll try to update my answer if I missed the mark.

You can create a `SelectList` out of a Model which includes the grouping. In my example, I have a "State/Province" field which is grouped by Country.

So in my Create method of my Controller, I have:

```
ViewData["StateList"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<State>(), "ID", "Name", "", "CountryID");
```

Where the paramaters are:

```
new SelectList(IEnumerable items,
   string dataValueField,
   string dataTextField,
   object selectedValue,
   string dataGroupField)
```

Then my View takes in this SelectList to automatically group elements.

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 200px;" asp-for="StateID" asp-items="ViewBag.StateList">
    <option>-- Select One --</option>
</select>
```

Where `StateID` is the database field, and `ViewBag.StateList` is the equivalent of the `ViewData["StateList"]` we created in the controller.